# External JavaScript function returning as "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to click on my logo to reload the page with this code:

```
<img class='logo' src='branding/logo2.png' onclick='reload(); console.log("on")'>
```

with this JavaScript:

```
async function price() {
    /* my code */
}

async function reload() {
price()
}
```

I get an undefined error. I only have the reload function because I thought that would fix it. Any fixes?

Comment: You'll need to post more code than that. Why are the functions `async`?

Comment: If you're attempting to refresh the page, you need `location.reload();`, not just `reload();`. If you're trying to do something else, we're going to need to see more code

Comment: @rossipedia i'm trying to just reload my code and not the whole page.

Comment: @Pointy i was using awaits earlier on but changed my code.

Comment: You are also missing an await before the price()

Comment: Functions are not in `window` scope, if You want to create window scoped function create it by `window.myFunc: function(){}`